# If a function is integrable, does it also have finite integral given any counting measure?

Tags: real-analysis

If the integral of a function $f$ is $L^1$,

\begin{equation} \int f dx < \infty \end{equation}

Does the same function have finite integral under any countable counting measure,

\begin{equation} \sum f(x_{i}) d\mu(x_{i}) < \infty \end{equation}

for any sequance $\{ x_{i} \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$?

I wanna say yes, due to the latter being the same as simple functions on point sets. But also we might loose cancelation of areas when throwing away alot of stuff in this fashion.

Comment: I don't think that $\sum f(x_i)d\mu (x_i) $ is a standard notation

Comment: @Jakobian it is any counting measure with weight 1 on each point.

Comment: @user7534 Then you should write $\int fd\mu$ or $\sum_{i} f(x_i)\mu(\{x_i\})$. Not a mixup of both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, first of all, please make sure you get your notation correct, otherwise it's hard to be sure what you're asking.  I *think* you mean to say that $f\in L_1$, not $L_2$.  It would also be nice to have the domain of $f$, which I assume from context is $(0,\infty)$.  Also, if you want to talk about an integral over the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, the proper notation is
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i).$$
Of course, the answer is no.  Consider the function $f=\boldsymbol{1}_\mathbb{N}$.

There are special conditions under which the answer is yes.  By the Integral Test, if $f$ is nonnegative, continuous, and decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and $\int f<\infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges.  In fact, so does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)$, provided $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is increasing with $\inf|x_{i+1}-x_i|>0$.

Comment: Thanks, you mind clarify the last part with a lower bound on the increment?

Comment: @user7534 Sure. The gritty details are similar to the proof of the Integral Test itself (see wikipedia for an outline), but the underlying idea is quite intuitive. Suppose each $x_i\in(i,i+1]$. Then $f(x_i)\leq f(i)$ and so $\sum f(x_i)\leq \sum f(i)$, the latter of which we already decided converges. Of course, it doesn't matter if we scale the $x_i$'s or cut out some of them.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined as $f=\mathbf1_{\mathbb Z}$ then $\int f(x)^2dx=0$ but $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}f(n)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, but I think the answer is essentially, "no".

You can change the value of an integrable function on any countable set of points without changing integrability or the integral. So just define it to be large enough at each point at which your "counting measure" is supported to make the sum diverge.